# Discord.js Send content of used command to admin

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am not 100% sure on how to do this or if its possible but is there a way that a user could do

`#command issue here`

and send the issue towards a specific channel or admin?

So its basically like a way to report issues towards admins of the bot

I would appreciate the help and thanks in advance

```
module.exports = {
  name: "reportissue",
  description: "Report an issue you are experiencing with the bot",
  permissions: {
    channel: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES", "EMBED_LINKS"],
    member: ["ADMINISTRATOR"],
  },
  aliases: ["report", "issue"],
   run: async (client, message, args, { GuildDB }) => {


// I have removed this since its not the correct usage
// message.channel.send("issue");

    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this would work

```
const query = args.join (" ")

      if(!query) return message.channel.send("Please specify the bug you want to report")

      const reportEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Bug!')
      .addField('Author', message.author.toString(), true)
      .addField('Report', query)
      .addField('Guild', message.guild.name, true)
      .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
      .setTimestamp()
        message.channel.send('We are extremely sorry for this issue. Your report has successfully been submitted and will be looked into. \n Regards, AuraBot Team')
      client.channels.cache.get('id').send(reportEmbed);
```

Comment: @foreverlost no problem